# Calling procedures from different Schemas MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, schema

I have used MySQL for a few months and have really liked it.  I have a question about using procedures between different schemas.

To give some context, I am working with a local copy of a database from my job.  When I create procedures for the database, some of them I want to upload to the server, but others I rather want to keep on my local computer.  However, the ones that I keep in my computer will be deleted when I load a new backup copy of the production database.

Where would be a safe place or way to save these procedures in my computer.  Should I keep a separate schema for my local procedure, and then will I be able to call them from the backed up schema?  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put procedures in a separate schema. Any query that references a table inside the procedure should be qualified by schema name.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT ... FROM dbname.tablename;
END
```